# Plotting errorbars with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot a line graph with errorbars with matplotlib (or if you have a better solution, really any plotting software). Similar to this, for example: [image]

I am using a python script to call a java process, and I need to plot the results.

Here's the Python script:

```
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arrSize = {100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000}

filename = "instance.txt"
iterations = input("Iterations: ")

for i in arrSize:
    print("\nArray Size: " + str(i) + "\n")
    cmdStr = "Java Driver " + filename + " " + str(i) + " " + str(iterations)
    output = subprocess.check_output(["java", "Driver", filename, str(i), str(iterations)])
    print(output.decode("utf-8").split())
```

The output from output.decode("utf-8").split() is a list of three elements, all floats. The idea is that I will run the test something like 30 times and then plot three lines with errorbars (one for each of the three elements in the output list). I am entirely new to plotting and still fairly new to python, so I might need some hand-holding in the process. Again, if you think there's a better way to do this besides matplotlib I am open to suggestions.

Comment: What are the x axis and y axis in your plot going to be?

Comment: I always start by looking through the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#statistics)

Comment: Yes, the gallery has an [errorbar example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_limits.html).